# Call laravel controller via command line

Tags: php, laravel

In kohana framework I can call controller via command line using

```
php5 index.php --uri=controller/method/var1/var2
```

Is it possible to call controller I want in Laravel 5 via cli? If yes, how to do this?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

There is no way so far (not sure if there will ever be). However you can create your own [Artisan Command](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/commands) that can do that. Create a command `CallRoute` using this:

```
php artisan make:console CallRoute
```

For Laravel 5.3 or greater you need to use `make:command` instead:

```
php artisan make:command CallRoute
```

This will generate a command class in `app/Console/Commands/CallRoute.php`. The contents of that class should look like this:

```
<?php namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CallRoute extends Command {

    protected $name = 'route:call';
    protected $description = 'Call route from CLI';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function fire()
    {
        $request = Request::create($this->option('uri'), 'GET');
        $this->info(app()['Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel']->handle($request));
    }

    protected function getOptions()
    {
        return [
            ['uri', null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'The path of the route to be called', null],
        ];
    }

}
```

You then need to register the command by adding it to the `$commands` array in `app/Console/Kernel.php`:

```
protected $commands = [
    ...,
    'App\Console\Commands\CallRoute',
];
```

You can now call any [route](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing) by using this command:

```
php artisan route:call --uri=/route/path/with/param
```

Mind you, this command will return a response as it would be sent to the browser, that means it includes the HTTP headers at the top of the output.

Comment: For Laravel 4: `php artisan command:make CallRoute`. The kernel is actually the router, so the command needs to have `$this->info(app()[\Illuminate\Routing\Router::class]->handle($request));`. The command is added to artisan in `app/start/artisan.php` with `Artisan::add(new CallRoute);`

Comment: This solution seems to have stopped working for Laravel 5.4, with this error: exception 'Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException' with message 'Target [\Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel] is not instantiable.'

Comment: Found a fix.  Instead of: app()['Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel'], use: app()->make(\Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class)

Answer (score 60):

I am using Laravel 5.0 and I am triggering controllers using this code:

```
$ php artisan tinker
$ $controller = app()->make('App\Http\Controllers\MyController');
$ app()->call([$controller, 'myMethodName'], []);
```

the last `[]` in the `app()->call()` can hold arguments such as `[user_id] => 10` etc'

Comment: is there a way to call this non-interactively?

Comment: php artisan tinker opens up a shell, into which I have to put the other 2 lines. But I would like to just have that executed, for I am putting it in a script. As of now I just solved by making line 2 and 3 a single one, and piping it into the first - was wondering if there was a better solution

Comment: hmm well I used this for tests so I just wrote each line at a time and saw the response after sending line 3

Comment: @grasshopper if you putting it in a script then this is the wrong tool. You should instead be using a custom artisan command. You can then simply run `php artisan mycommand` instead of `tinker`.

Comment: Thank you @JamesHulse, I solved for now by echoing the command and piping it to php artisan tinker. I am working on code which is not mine (never used laravel before), could you advise which tool should I use? I am initialising and bootstrapping a laravel application from vagrant provisioner

Comment: @grasshopper check out https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/artisan#writing-commands on how to create a command. You can even run these commands on a schedule if you need.

Comment: @Broshi - What is `Tinker` and `app()` here?

Comment: @151291 `tinker` is an artisan command which opens up a session that lets you interact with laravel, `app()` returns the application instance. these are 3 seperate commands, i've edited my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Instead of writing this whole app()->call([$controller, 'myMethodName'], []); it is easier to call it this way, $controller->someFunction()

Answer (score 22):

For Laravel 5.4:
php artisan make:command CallRoute

Then in `app/Console/Commands/CallRoute.php`:

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CallRoute extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'route:call {uri}';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'php artsian route:call /route';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $request = Request::create($this->argument('uri'), 'GET');
        $this->info(app()->make(\Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class)->handle($request));
    }

}
```

Then in `app/Console/Kernel.php`:

```php
protected $commands = [
    'App\Console\Commands\CallRoute'
];
```

Call like: `php artisan route:call /path`

Comment: This is a very elegant solution for Laravel 5.5 too.

Comment: Works in Laravel 5.6 too.

Comment: Nice solution. Remember to add `'App\Console\Commands\CallRoute'` under `$commands` in the `config/tinker.php` config file so that you can run this command from tinker.

Comment: In Lumen this generates: `Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel] is not instantiable`

Comment: This answer is better than the excepted one.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it in this way too. First, create the command using

```
php artisan command:commandName
```

Now in the `handle` of the command, call the controller and trigger the method.
Eg,

```
public function handle(){
 $controller = new ControllerName(); // make sure to import the controller
 $controller->controllerMethod();
}
```

This will actually do the work. Hope, this helps.

**DEPENDENCY INJECTION WON'T WORK**

Comment: DI is ignored calling method in this way.

Comment: DI - dependency injection. Right?

Comment: There are no commands defined in the "command" namespace.

Answer (score 6):

Laravel 5.7

Using tinker

```
 // URL: http://xxx.test/calendar?filter[id]=1&anotherparam=2
 $cc = app()->make('App\Http\Controllers\CalendarController');
 app()->call([$cc, 'getCalendarV2'], ['filter[id]'=>1, 'anotherparam' => '2']);
```

Answer (score 1):

#### To version 8 of laravel.

**First step: type command in terminal**
`php artisan tinker`

**Secound step:**

```php
$instante = new MyController(null);
```

Or if argument by an instance of model, then, pass name model class. 
Example:

```php
$instante = new MyController(new MyModelHere());
```

`Press enter`.

Finally, call method with  `$instante->myMethod()` here.

See:
[image]