# Laravel 5 - how to run a Controller method from an Artisan Command?

Tags: php, laravel, controller, command, laravel-artisan

I need some code from my Controller to run every ten minutes. Easy enough with `Scheduler` and `Commands`. But. I've created a `Command`, registered it with `Laravel Scheduler` (in `Kernel.php`) and now I am unable to instantiate the `Controller`. I know it's a wrong way to approach this problem, but I just needed a quick test. Is there a way, mind you a hacky way, to accomplish this? Thank you.

Update #1:

The `Command`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\Http\Controllers\StatsController;


class UpdateProfiles extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'update-profiles';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Updates profiles in database.';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        StatsController::updateStats('<theProfileName>');
    }
}
```

`updateStats()` method in `StatsController.php`

```
public static function updateStats($theProfileName) { 
   // the body
}
```

This returns a `FatalErrorException`:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException] 
syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)
```

Update #2:

Turns out that I've had an typo in the `updateStats()` method, but the answer by @alexey-mezenin works like a charm! It is also enough to import the `Controller` into the `Command`:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\StatsController;
```

And then initialize it as you'd do normally:

```
public function handle() {
   $statControl        = new StatsController;
   $statControl->updateStats('<theProfileName>');
}
```

Comment: You could map a route to the controller method and use [this command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28866821/call-laravel-controller-via-command-line/28868350#28868350) to run the route path.

Comment: Why not do it the right way move the code you need to run out of the controller and call it from a command/controller respectively. Much cleaner than a hacky solution.

Comment: I fully agree, but when you encounter the stuff for the first time and just want to learn, you inevitably use hacky solutions. After you learn enough, understand the concepts, you refactor it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use `use Full\Path\To\Your\Controller;` in your command code and use method statically:

```
public static function someStaticMethod()
{
    return 'Hello';
}
```

In your command code:

```
echo myClass::someStaticMethod();
```

Comment: Spasibo. I've tried it, but unfortunatelly, it didn't work. This is what it returned: `[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)`

Comment: I mean the code with 'unexpected if'. You have syntax error in a controller or other class.

Comment: I think this exception comes straight out of Symfony, how can I determine which file is it coming from? When I run the command using Artisan, I only get that, nothing else, no stack trace.

Comment: Check Laravel logs, maybe you'll find trace there. Also check all last changes you made.

Comment: Aww. Wow. A semicolon wasn't there in the end, you're right, just a typo in the updateStats() method. It works now! Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad I could help, comrade. )

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin hi, I encountered the same problem and my error log: [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
  Using $this when not in object context. How can I solve it?