# Laravel Artisan route:call Throws MySQL Error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using `Artisan` to call a `Laravel 5 Route` via the command line. I created a command line controller by following the directions in this post: [Call laravel controller via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28866821/call-laravel-controller-via-command-line).

**I don't receive any errors when I navigate to this route in a web browser**.  This route performs an API call and inserts data into a MySQL database by using a `Laravel` `Model` I created called `Ticker`.

When I can call my route from the CLI, like so:

```
$ php artisan route:call /d17059dfce4c09ef5e437b1d9455f7c6
```

I'm getting a `Laravel` error (where `truncate 'tickers'` is the first SQL command executed in the controller which the route calls, and `tickers` is the table within the database), stating:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: truncate `tickers`)
```

Because I only seem to be getting the error when executing this route through the command line, it leads me to believe there must be some issue with the command line script `App\Console\Commands\CallRoute.php` which looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Http\Requests;

class CallRoute extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'route:call {uri}';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'php artsian route:call /route';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $request = Request::create($this->argument('uri'), 'GET');
        $this->info(app()->make(\Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class)->handle($request));
    }
}
```

Any help troubleshooting or resolving this error would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: that error usully relates to your mysql connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass in `/d17059dfce4c09ef5e437b1d9455f7c6` as an option rather than an argument. It's interpreting that as a directory.

```
php artisan route:call --uri=/d17059dfce4c09ef5e437b1d9455f7c6
```

Update the command signature to include the `uri` option:

```
protected $signature = 'route:call {--uri=}';
```

Command:

```
class CallRoute extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'route:call {--uri=}';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'php artsian route:call /route';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $request = Request::create($this->option('uri'), 'GET');
        $this->info(app()->make(\Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class)->handle($request));
    }
}
```

Comment: When I issue that command I get the following error: `The "--uri" option does not exist.`

Comment: You need to define `uri` in your command's signature. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Weird, but now the error switched to: `The "uri" argument does not exist. `

Comment: Update the `handle` method to use `$this->option('uri')` rather than `$this->argument()`

Comment: Those errors about the `uri` are now resolved, but I'm back to square one with the original error stated in my OP and my database still isn't being updated

Comment: Hmm, does your db connection use`127.0.0.1` or `localhost`? If you're using a socket, check your `php.ini` and make sure the `mysql.default_socket` setting is pointing to the correct file.

Comment: I have it set to `127.0.0.1` in both the `.env` and `config/database.php` files to force `PDO` to use the TCP protocol.

Comment: Does the mysql error log show the connection attempt being made with the correct settings?

Comment: I don't see an entry being made at all in the error log when I run the command

Comment: Any additional ideas? I'm still having trouble understanding what is happening.  I know I could create a standalone PHP script with MySQL connection, but I should probably use the Laravel framework to get the most use out of the Models and database connection, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try to take a look at this issue.

[PDOException SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723803/pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

I had similar issues when my **php-cli** had troubles connection to mysql, while my **php-fpm** was working fine(it could also be the reason why you don't have an error while you navigate to this route in the browser). I had to enable mysql pdo extension in my php-cli config.

Just run `php -v` in the console, and if you see something similar:

```
PHP 7.2.1 (cli) (built: Jan  8 2018 23:39:24) ( NTS )
```

It probably means you have to enable pdo support for php-cli

Comment: I located my php-cli config for MAMP in `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.1/conf/php.ini` and added the line for `extension=pdo_mysql.so` but I'm still receiving the same error when I attempt to CLI command execution

Comment: Honestly, I don't know what I did to fix it, but it is fixed now.  I tried changing several things and cleared the artisan config cache and its working now.  I've started removing/un-doing the fixes I tried one-by-one and now I'm back to square one, but its still working...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you meant to say `TRUNCATE TABLE tickers`?  Are you throwing away everything it that table?

Comment: I am throwing away everything in the table, but the syntax in my OP isn't the actual syntax being used; I'm using a Laravel Model to perform the operation which evaluates to what the error displays.  Again, everything works fine in a web browser, just not from CLI.  In any event, the issue is now resolved.

Answer (score 0):

`php artisan` command create and object of command classes(Custom commands you have created). This is to fetch the list of available commands and options.

You might have added database query (`truncate table tickers`) Any of your Commands files constructor (`__construct()`).