# How to send data from scheduled cron to Laravel controller?

Tags: php, laravel, controller, cron

How to pass data from a cron job to a controller in Laravel?

We have a Laravel command called WordOfTheHour. In it I am connection to the database and pick a random word from a table with 9,500 records. How to pass this data from the cron to the controller?

Should it be some kind of POST request?

Comment: here is a good example to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28866821/call-laravel-controller-via-command-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example:**

```
$result = app('App\Http\Controllers\UserCtrl')->login($param1, $param2...);
```

- "UserCtrl" is the controller
- "login" is the method in that controller
- "$param1", "$param2" are the parameters of that method.