# How to call a method of controller?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have to run a script every hour. So what I did in server is call `myfile.php` file every hour which runs my static function `runT()`.

Now my problem is after this `runT()` function is executed i have to run a method  **test** under a controller **MyController**.

### myfile.php

```
include "Helper.php";

Helper::runT();
```

### Helper.php

```
public static function runT() {
        ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
        $conn = self::getDbConnection();
```

### MyController.php

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
   public function test() {
```

Comment: This is relation question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365169/access-controller-method-from-another-controller-in-laravel-5

Comment: You can try with *CallRote* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28866821/call-laravel-controller-via-command-line

Comment: You should use "Task Scheduling"

Answer (score 2):

```
app(MyController::class)->test();
```

This will resolve an instance of `MyController`, it will do the jobs like `dependency injection` for you, and then call the `test` method.

Comment: so I just add app(MyController::class)->test() inside runT function ?

Comment: Yes, of cause you should use fully namespace.

Comment: but i am getting following error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function app() in C:\xampp\htdocs\myapi\assets\auto\Helper.php

Comment: hmm, if you haven't import composer autoload file, you will get this error. You can use import the autoload file like this, `require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php'; require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';`, the path you should change to your locally relative path

Comment: I dont understand

Comment: And beside, to auto run a job, you should use the the [artisan](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/artisan)

Answer (score 0):

to call controller method.use base_url.

```
 $.post('controller/method', $("#formid").serialize(), function (data) {
}
```