# Laravel 8 Call a route via cron

Tags: ubuntu, cron, laravel-8

I am attempting to invoke a route as a cron job.
Have attempted several guides such as this:

[Call laravel controller via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28866821/call-laravel-controller-via-command-line)
and
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/croning-a-route

Which leads to this addition in Kernel:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule) {
    $schedule->call(function () {
        (new Cron_c)->start();
    })->everyMinute();
}
```

Which does nothing but output 'Callback' when testing using

```
php /var/www/html/mySite/artisan schedule:run
```

outputs

```
[2022-07-11T15:27:50+00:00] Running scheduled command: Callback
```

The cron job code runs fine when entering the route into the browser and it outputs log info and on screen.

Comment: I didn't downvote but if you're going to blame me for it, maybe I should. Your complaint is about the SO rules which I quoted and linked to. If you have a complaint about the SO rules, take it up with the moderators, not me.

Comment: [Why not upload images in questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: **Which does nothing but output 'Callback' when testing using** What are you expecting from it? Add more to the scope so we can at least reproduce what you are facing.

Comment: I wanted to copy-paste the output you're getting so I can start searching and investigating ... but it's an image.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is Laravel Commands: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/artisan

With `php artisan make:command <your Command Name>` you can create Commands.
Those will be created in the `App/Console/Commands` directory.

You will there find in the newly created class a function called `handle()` where you would put your code.

The CLI command to call your function will be set in the property `protected $signature = "datadimensionsCommand";`, which is prepared for you as well.

So your cronjob would call:

```bash
$> php /path/to/your/app/artisan datadimensionsCommand
```

Checkout the docs for a deeper dive!